# fomat a single HLOOKUP as date when it is part of string with several HLOOKUPs in Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am using an arrayformula with an IF logic resulting in several HLOOKUPs that I would like to end with a date format

I want a result that looks like this: `My Name, 10/1/1972`
I end up with a result that looks like this: `My Name, 26573`

```
ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF...

...&", "&(HLOOKUP(("Date"),Form!$A$1:$DG,D2:D,false
```

I tried applying using `TO_DATE(), TO_TEXT()`
I tried changing the formatting of the source column of date to format>number>date

but I still end up with the 5 digit instead of the number.

How do I modify to get a date output?

Comment: share a sample of your sheet or the full formula

Comment: Use `TEXT(YOUR_DATE,"DATE_FORMAT")`

Comment: Thanks this worked, sort of. Unusure if it will work in longer array as when I tried it formed an error, but I was able to get xxx , 78654 in a separate column where I used Right (B:B,5) along with suggested fix and it did work. I will work on a sheet for it and post, im just swampted right now. Thanks for patience.